# Accessing widget from android application

Tags: java, android, widget

I am trying to add weather widget into my application. I used this code to find target weather widget:

```
public class widgetTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, AppWidgetHostView> {
final static int APPWIDGET_HOST_ID = 1;
final static String WEATHER_PACKEGE = "accuweather.android";
final static String WEATHER_CLASS = "accuweather.android.widgets.AL_WidgetProvider";

@Override
protected AppWidgetHostView doInBackground(Context... arg0) {
    AppWidgetHostView hostView = null;
    AppWidgetManager AWmanager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(arg0[0]);
    AppWidgetHost AWHost = new AppWidgetHost(arg0[0], APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo AWProviderInfo = new AppWidgetProviderInfo();

    int AWId = AWHost.allocateAppWidgetId();

    List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> AWProviderInfos = new ArrayList<AppWidgetProviderInfo>();
    AWProviderInfos  = AWmanager.getInstalledProviders();

    for(int j = 0; j < AWProviderInfos.size(); j++)
    {

        if (AWProviderInfos.get(j).provider.getPackageName().equals("com."+WEATHER_PACKEGE) && AWProviderInfos.get(j).provider.getClassName().equals("com."+WEATHER_CLASS))
        {
            AWProviderInfo = AWProviderInfos.get(j);
            break;
        }
    }
    hostView = AWHost.createView(arg0[0], AWId, AWProviderInfo);
    hostView.setAppWidget(AWId, AWProviderInfo);

    return hostView;
}
```

}

After that I tried to add AppWidgetHostView into my Activity:

```
AppWidgetHostView weatherWidget = WT.execute(this).get();
LLWeather.addView(weatherWidget);
```

It worked but widget showed "Downloading weather data"(internet permissions granted to this activity) and freezed so I cant interact with it.
Any ideas how to fix it and access to widget functions?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use get() on your asynctask call as it will not be async anymore. The result of doInBackground will be available in onPostExecute. In onPostExecute you call LLWeather.addView.